# Magento 2 Oauth 2.0 with postman

Tags: magento2, oauth, postman

I want to make an authorization through OAuth 2.0 through postman. I have setup an integration now what should I do next?

Comment: Get token for user and admin.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is compliant Oauth 1.0a check following link [Api document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html) it might help you .